# How to align Ionic elements button or image with text in one line

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, button, text

In Ionic application, I'm trying to align image and button in one line with text  in .css and .html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <img class="myImg" src="assets/img.png"/>
    <ion-title class="text">Hello</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

here is my .css:

```
 .myImg{
     width: 27px;
      float: left;
    }
    
    .text{
      text-align: left;
    }
```

left is  actual result, right is a desired:

[image]

and same with text and image:

```
<ion-label class="myLab">Text</ion-label>
<ion-button class="myBtn">Text</ion-button>
```

here is css:

```
.myLab{
  padding-left: 19px;
}

.myBtn{
  float: right !important;
  padding-right: 19px !important;
}
```

or this way:

```
<ion-label for="btn">text</ion-label>
<span><ion-button name="btn">Text</ion-button></span>
```

css:

```
ion-label {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

span {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 4px 0 6px;
}

ion-button {
  width: 70%;
}
```

and this:

```
<ion-label id="el1">text</ion-label>
<ion-button id="el2">Text</ion-button>
```

css:

```
#el1 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

#el2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}
```

but result looks like this:

[image]

desired:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with ion-header you can use ion-item

```
<ion-header class="header">
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-item class="ion-no-padding" lines="none">
            <ion-avatar slot="start">
                <ion-img src="assets/img.png"></ion-img>
            </ion-avatar>
            <ion-label>TEXT</ion-label>
            <ion-buttons slot="end">
                <ion-button color="primary" fill="clear">
                    Enter
                    <ion-icon slot="end" name="log-in"></ion-icon>
                </ion-button>
            </ion-buttons>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

[it gives this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwHuZ.png)